# Getting a proper date and time format from DATETIME in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in a table as a 'Last Logged In Date/Time' section for my admin page.

When I echo out the value I want it to display in a nice format.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$last_logged_in = $rows['last_logged_in']; 
echo $last_logged_in->format('M j Y g:i A');
```

I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on string

What am I doing wrong here. How can I make it display in a nice formatted way?

Please & Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you want to create a DateTime object first ?! -> `$last_logged_in = new DateTime("@" . $rows['last_logged_in']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL stores dates as string, and `format` is a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/class.datetime.php) method:

```
$last_logged_in = $rows['last_logged_in'];
$datetime_obj   = new \DateTime($last_logged_in);
echo $datetime_obj->format('M j Y g:i A');
```